# What is '_' doing here?

Tags: python, jupyter

I used a generator expression and then a list comprehension, what does '_' do here?

```
x = (i for i in [1, 2, 3])
[_ for i in x]
```

it gives such output

`[]`

`[[], [], []]`

`[[[], [], []], [[], [], []], [[], [], []]]`

```
[[[[], [], []], [[], [], []], [[], [], []]],
 [[[], [], []], [[], [], []], [[], [], []]],
 [[[], [], []], [[], [], []], [[], [], []]]]
```

on running two lines multiple times

Comment: It should not be a valid expression. It gives just an error. `NameError: name '_' is not defined`

Comment: Please only tag with appropriate tags. This has nothing to do with [tag:underscore.js] and I suspect not with [tag:jupyter], either.

Comment: What did you intend the `_` to do?

Comment: I ran in google colab

Answer (score 3):

If you're running the code at a Python REPL (which I think you are), then the underscore is a built-in variable that holds the last value calculated (and is updated by the REPL as values are calculated).

For example:

```
>>> x = 5   #  this is not _
>>> _ ** 2  #  so referencing it will raise a NameError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name '_' is not defined
>>> 5  #  the result of this will be the value referenced by _
5
>>> _ ** 2  #  now referencing it is okay
25
>>> _ ** 2  #  note that now the value of _ is 25 (the last value calculated)
625
>>>  #  and here its value is 625 (and so on)
```